# how to call render function of custom columns in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi some one please help on the below logic.

I use to get a dynamic columns from the user, based on that i need to create a dataTable, i have written the below code to read the columns, i need to apply the render function from some columns which have which will display the code value, please share me some idea how to do that

```js
function createDataTableColumns(ColumnsName)
{
  var colum = ColumnsName.split(",");
  $.each(colum, function (i, item) {
    var operationColumns = new Object();
    operationColumns.sTitle = item;
    operationColumns.data = item;
    operationColumns.push(operationColumn);

  })
}

function fnCreateTable(Data, tableID) {
  if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#' + tableID)) {
    var table1 = $('#customRptTable').DataTable();
    table1.destroy();
    $('#' + tableID + 'tbody').unbind('click');
  }
  $("#divOperation").show();
  debugger;
  var tableLicense = $('#' + tableID).DataTable({
    "data": Data,
    "aoColumns": operationColumns,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "searching": false,
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "100%",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
  });

  $("#divOperation").show();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define columns and in side that u can use render. Target attribute allows you to define which column you are changing. You no need to loop, render function parameter itself is each value of the targeted column.

```
 var tableLicense = $('#' + tableID).DataTable({
    "data": Data,
    "aoColumns": operationColumns,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "searching": false,
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "100%",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
"columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": null, // Use the full data source object for the renderer's source
    "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
        // here call your method
     }
  } ]
  });
```

Comment: for more detail check this link https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render